# Why does this code in VBA Power Point work fine witout Dim commands for numbers?

Tags: vba, variables, integer, numbers, dimension

From one of VBA tutorials I learned that variables contining numbers should be firstly declared as integers:

```
Dim mynumber as integer
```

But, please, look at this code:

```
Sub math()
   A = 23
   B = 2
   ABSumTotal = A + B
   strMsg = "The answer is " & "$" & ABSumTotal & "."
   MsgBox strMsg
   strMsg = "The answer is " & "$" & Sqr(ABSumTotal) & "."
   MsgBox strMsg 
End Sub
```

No variables are declared here as integer, but it still works just fine. Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, VB does not require variable declarations.  This has caused lots of frustration because it means that typos go undetected until something breaks at runtime.

To change this, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the file.